# JavaFX: How to add calculated Integer value to TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a bill table where I want to list all products which are on the bill. I saved the `ProductInBill` objects within an `ArrayList<ProductInBill>` on the bill.

When I created a `TableView` my common approach is to create the JavaFX fields. On the controller class, I have my fields:

```
@FXML public TableColumn<ProductInBill, String> finishedBillProductNameColumn;
@FXML public TableColumn<Integer, Integer> finishedBillProductNumberColumn;
@FXML public TableColumn<ProductInBill, Integer> finishedBillProductPriceBruttoLabel;
@FXML public TableColumn<Integer, Integer> finishedBillProductTotalAmountColumn;
@FXML public TableView finishedBillProductTable;
```

Then I am using a `setUp()` method with the code like:

```
private void setUpFinishedBillProductTable() {
    finishedBillProductNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProductInBill, String>("productName"));
    finishedBillProductPriceBruttoLabel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProductInBill, Integer>("productPrice"));
}
```

Also there is an `updateBillTable()` method to load the necessary `ProductInBill` objects, save them to an TableList and give it to the table.

```
 private void updateFinishedBillProductTable(Bill bill) {

    LOG.info("Start reading all Products from Bill");

    for(ProductInBill product : bill.getProducts()){
          finishedBillProductCurrent.add(product);
    }
    finishedBillProductTable.getItems().clear();


    if(!finishedBillProductCurrent.isEmpty()) {
        for (ProductInBill p : finishedBillProductCurrent) {
                finishedBillProductTableList.add(p);
        }

        //here i want to calculate some other Integer values based on the ProductInBill values and insert them to the table too.  

        finishedBillProductTable.setItems(finishedBillProductTableList);
    }
}
```

This is all working very good. My problem now is, that I have also a field on my `TableView` with calculated Integer values which I don't want to save within an object.

Take for example the `finishedBillProductNumberColumn`. I want iterate on my `ArrayList`, find all products with the same name and populate the number of the same items to the table.

How can I do this? I found only solutions where I have to use a value from my object to insert something to my `TableView`.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to write a custom CellValueFactory for those case instead of using premade ones. Using [PropertyValueFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) is just an handy short cut to fill cells with members.

For your example:

```
 finishedBillProductNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ProductInBill, String>("productName"));
```

is just a shorter way to do:

```
finishedBillProductNameColumn.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> {
    ProductInBill productInBill = cellData.getValue();
    return data == null ? null : new SimpleStringProperty(productInBill.getProductName());
 });
```

That being said, i have an 100% preference for the second syntax. Because on the first one if you rename the member, and you forgot to change it there, you won't know there is a mistake until you get there in the application. Plus it allow to display different value than just the members.

As a concrete example for your `finishedBillProductNumberColumn` you could do:

First change the definition(the first Generic type is the one received with `cellData.getValue()`:

```
@FXML public TableColumn<ProductInBill, Integer> finishedBillProductNumberColumn;
```

and then define the CellValueFactory you want like:

```
finishedBillProductNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory( cellData -> {
    ProductInBill productInBill = cellData.getValue();

    if(productionInBill != null){
        Long nbProduct = finishedBillProductTable.getItems().stream().filter(product -> product.getProductName().equals(productInBill.getProductName())).count();

        return new SimpleIntegerProperty(nbProduct.intValue()).asObject();
    }
    return null;
});
```

Hope it helped!